# Wildfly Swarm security domain configuration

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wildfly, wildfly-swarm

We are trying to migrate a project from Wildfly 10 to Wildfly Swarm 2017.6, and we have a reached a stumbling block porting the security-domain. Our security domain is configured as follows:

```
<security-domain name="sec-id">
   <authentication-jaspi>
   <login-module-stack name="sec-id-module-stack">
   <login-module code="com.obbi.domain.security.loginmodule.jwt.JWTLoginModule" flag="sufficient" module="com.obbi.domain.security">
   <module-option name="expectedIssuer" value="CN=DI SIT signer"/>
   <module-option name="expectedAudience" value="Obbi"/>
   <module-option name="allowedClockSkewInSeconds" value="30"/>
   <module-option name="validateTokenSignature" value="false"/>
   <module-option name="maxFutureValidityInMinutes" value="525600"/>
   <module-option name="keyStoreFilePath" value="C:/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/configuration/keystore.jks"/>
   <module-option name="keyStorePassword" value="obbi123"/>
   <module-option name="validateCertificate" value="false"/>
   <module-option name="loadSystemPrincipals" value="true"/>
   <module-option name="loadSystemPrincipalsEndpoint" value="https://test.obbi.co.za:9443/services/v1/obbi-id?page=0&amp;size=1000&amp;username=%s"/>
   <module-option name="skipAllValidators" value="true"/>
   </login-module>
   </login-module-stack>
   <auth-module code="com.obbi.domain.security.JASPICServerAuthModule" flag="required" login-module-stack-ref="sec-id-module-stack"/>
   </authentication-jaspi>
</security-domain>
```

We also have a standard module configured on com.obbi.domain.security. The module is just a standard module as follows:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="com.obbi.domain.security">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="domain-service-security-jboss-2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="domain-service-security-client-2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="jose4j-0.5.0.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <dependencies>
    <module name="org.jboss.as.web"/>
    <module name="org.jboss.logging"/>
    <module name="org.picketbox"/>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.security.auth.message.api"/>
    <module name="javax.servlet.api"/>
  </dependencies>
</module>
```

I can't find any wildfly swarm security fragment mappings that match to the subsystem. May I ask if they do exist, and if there is any documentation on them, of if anyone can assist in this forum can assist?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the `org.wildfly.swarm.security` fraction:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
    <artifactId>security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Documentation can be found in the [reference guide](https://reference.wildfly-swarm.io/fractions/security.html), usage looks like:

```
SecurityFraction
        .defaultSecurityFraction()
        .securityDomain(new SecurityDomain("remote").classicAuthentication(new ClassicAuthentication()
                .loginModule(new LoginModule("Remoting")
                        .code("Remoting")
                        .flag(Flag.OPTIONAL)
                        .moduleOption("password-stacking", "useFirstPass"))
                .loginModule(new LoginModule("RealmDirect")
                        .code("RealmDirect")
                        .flag(Flag.REQUIRED)
                        .moduleOption("password-stacking", "useFirstPass"))));
```

For your case, the call to `classicAuthentication()` should be replaced with `jaspiAuthentication()`. The login module can be deployed like any other module on Swarm.

Comment: Thanks Robby I will try it

Answer (score 0):

Managed to configure it as follows:

```
swarm.fraction(new SecurityFraction()
        .securityDomain("sec-id", (sd) -> {
        sd.jaspiAuthentication(jaspi -> {
        jaspi.authModule("basic", value -> {
        value.code("com.obbi.domain.security.loginmodule.jwt.JWTLoginModule")
        .flag(Flag.SUFFICIENT)
        .module("com.obbi.domain.security")
        .moduleOption("expectedIssuer", "CN=DI SIT signer")
        .moduleOption("expectedAudience", "Obbi")
        .moduleOption("allowedClockSkewInSeconds", "30")
        .moduleOption("validateTokenSignature", "false")
        .moduleOption("maxFutureValidityInMinutes", "525600")
        .moduleOption("keyStoreFilePath", "C:/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/configuration/keystore.jks")
        .moduleOption("keyStorePassword", "pass123")
        .moduleOption("validateCertificate", "false")
        .moduleOption("loadSystemPrincipals", "true")
        .moduleOption("loadSystemPrincipalsEndpoint", "https://test.obbi.co.za:9443/services/v1/obbi-id?page=0&amp;size=1000&amp;username=%s")
        .moduleOption("skipAllValidators", "true");
        });
        });
        }));
```